# How to read from one line separated with only whitespace?

Tags: java, integer, whitespace, java.util.scanner, boolean-expression

```
    int a; 
    int b;                           
    int c;

    Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);

    //how to read three integers with white space delimiter 
    System.out.print("Enter the 3 edges of the triangle to be calculated: "); 
    int numbers = input.nextInt();

    //then turn 3 integers into boolean form
    //this is only the algorithm
    Boolean isTriangle = ((a+b>c)  && (b+c > a)  && (c+a > b));

           System.out.print(isTriangle);

    else

            System.out.print(isTriangle);
```

So instead of entering 3 integers in a separate line or in a newline i want them all to be in the same line just separated with whitespace. Do I need to change standard input as string then just parse it after for the boolean part? I am confuse because after entering the integers I don't know where to store them to use for the boolean part.

Edited part:

```
    public static void main(String[] args){
    int x;
    int y;
    int z;

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter three edges: ");

    x = input.nextInt();
    y = input.nextInt();
    z = input.nextInt();

    boolean isTriangle = ((x+y>z)  && (y+z > x)  && (z+x > y));

    if (isTriangle){
        System.out.print("Can edges " + x + ", " + y + ", " + z + " form a triangle"+ isTriangle);
    }
    else {
        System.out.print("Can edges " + x + ", " + y + ", " + z + " form a triangle"+ isTriangle);
    }
    }
```

why is it that when i call  x y and z in system.out they don't show the entered input but when i only put the isTriangle on system.out it gives me output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just call the `nextInt` three times.

```
System.out.print("Enter the 3 edges of the triangle to be calculated: ");
a = input.nextInt();
b = input.nextInt();
c = input.nextInt();
```

With input

```
5 5 5
```

It prints `true`.

You'll have to check wether there are three numbers available (use `input.hasNextInt()` **before** `input.nextInt()`):

```
System.out.print("Enter the 3 edges of the triangle to be calculated: ");
if(input.hasNextInt()) {
    a = input.nextInt();
} else {
    //handle it, you don't have ints!
}
if(input.hasNextInt()) {
    b = input.nextInt();
} else {
    //handle it, you have just one int!
}
if(input.hasNextInt()) {
    c = input.nextInt();
} else {
    //handle it, you have just two ints!
}
```

[DEMO](http://ideone.com/gg6T6V)

Comment: I thought about this first but I also thought maybe there was another way of reading the input. Thank you!

Comment: how do you use the hasNextInt?

Comment: is it possible to do this?
Line 1 Right: Enter three edges: Can edges 5, 1, and 1 form a triangle? false

like the system.out.print is all in the same line?

Answer (score 1):

It's better to use below.

```
    String values=scanner.next();//if your input 5 5 5
   String numinString[]=values.split(" ");
   int a=Integer.parseInt(numinString[0]);//a=5
   int b=Integer.parseInt(numinString[1]);//b=5
   int c=Integer.parseInt(numinString[2]);//c=5
```

Comment: Your example won't work. The `next()` method of class `Scanner` reads up untile the first space. So if the input is `5 5 5`, `scanner.next()` will read just the first `5`.

Comment: use scanner.nextLine();

Comment: I know, I was just pointing out that your solution is wrong, you should update your answer

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way:

```
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    // how to read three integers with white space delimiter
    System.out.print("Enter the 3 edges of the triangle to be calculated: ");
    a = input.nextInt();
    b = input.nextInt();
    c = input.nextInt();
    // then turn 3 integers into boolean form
    // this is only the algorithm
    Boolean isTriangle = ((a + b > c) && (b + c > a) && (c + a > b));
    if (isTriangle)
        System.out.print(isTriangle);

    else

        System.out.print(isTriangle);
```